Google App Script Export PDF isn't syncing
I have the following data in my Spreadsheet
Since the latest doc_no is TRY/2024/05/06/0707857126, I want to generate a PDF according to that number. Here's the PDF Spreadsheet:

I'm able to generate the spreadsheet according to the latest data. Now i want to export them as PDF by using the following script:
let url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + sheetExportId + "/export" +
    "?format=pdf" +
    "&size=A4" +
    "&portrait=true" +
    "&fitw=true" +
    "&sheetnames=false" +
    "&printtitle=false" +
    "&pagenumbers=false" +
    "&gridlines=false" +
    "&fzr=true" +
    "&gid=" + sheetId;
  let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token
    }
  });
  let blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName);
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderPdfId); // Change this to the desired folder

  // Check if a file with the same name already exists and delete it
  let existingFiles = folder.getFilesByName(blob.getName());
  if (existingFiles.hasNext()) {
    let existingFile = existingFiles.next();
    existingFile.setTrashed(true); // Move the existing file to trash
  }

  let pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob);

  console.log(`Sending email to ${emailRecipient}`);
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailRecipient,
    subject: emailSubject,
    body: emailBody,
    attachments: [pdfFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
  });

The email sent with false data. The sent data was TRY/2024/05/06/0707431726. What i expect is TRY/2024/05/06/0707857126.
The problem is, why did PDF spreadsheet export the spreadsheet with TRY/2024/05/06/0707431726 not TRY/2024/05/06/0707857126.
how do i resolve this?

Although, unfortunately from your showing script, I cannot know your whole script, how about adding SpreadsheetApp.flush() to the top of your showing script? So, please put it just before the line of let url = "https://,,, and test it again. If my guess was not correct, I apologize. At that time, can you provide your whole script?

Thanks @Tanaike . It worked like magic by adding 1 line of code: `SpreadsheetApp.flush() as you suggested.

Thank you for replying and testing it. From your reply, I found that my guess was correct. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
